# svn with hard links

Tags: linux, svn, hyperlink

I am using Apache Subversion (SVN) on Ubuntu. I have a file which is used in several sub-projects. So I use hard links to the same file.

After `svn commit`, it seems that the hard links become independent files (the link count becomes 1).

**Is it possible for SVN to keep the hard links?**

Comment: Does it work with symlinks? IIRC, svn does understand those and will preserve them.

Comment: Let me try again. Maybe I made some mistake. Thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subversion support symbolic links since 1.1 (2004).

Hard links are not recognized and handled as normal files.

See this also [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html)

> Versioning Symbolic Links
>
> On non-Windows platforms, Subversion is able to version files of the special type symbolic link (or “symlink”). A symlink is a file that acts as a sort of transparent reference to some other object in the filesystem, allowing programs to read and write to those objects indirectly by performing operations on the symlink itself.
>
> When a symlink is committed into a Subversion repository, Subversion remembers that the file was in fact a symlink, as well as the object to which the symlink “points.” When that symlink is checked out to another working copy on a non-Windows system, Subversion reconstructs a real filesystem-level symbolic link from the versioned symlink. But that doesn't in any way limit the usability of working copies on systems such as Windows that do not support symlinks. On such systems, Subversion simply creates a regular text file whose contents are the path to which the original symlink pointed. While that file can't be used as a symlink on a Windows system, it also won't prevent Windows users from performing their other Subversion-related activities.

Comment: Dear H.-Dirk Schmitt, I will try symbolic links to see if it works on my system. :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Hard links are normal files. You can only know that it linked from more places, because the link count is greater than 1.

One think you can do to have the same file in every project, is to use svn externals. In this way, one project will have the file that you want to share, and all the other will use that file.

You can read more about svn externals [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

Comment: Dear Augusto, do you think I can use symbolic link to solve the problem instead of using svn:externals?

Comment: Yes, you can, the only problem I see, is that the file you want to share must be in the correct place wherever you deploy your applications. If you use svn external, you don't need to care, as the file will be in the directory you want.